# Sudden dropoff in Azure queue performance

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Short version: What reasons could there be for a sudden, dramatic, and seemingly permanent increase in the rate of timing-out Azure queue requests?

It's going to be difficult to provide all of the details that could possibly be relevant here, but here's a start:

This is an Azure application (SDK v2.0) with a WCF service placing work requests on a queue (roughly 100k calls a day) and a couple of worker roles which process the queue. We've got New Relic monitoring with the latest .NET agent (3.3.38).

We've run into an issue in our latest release, deployed a few days ago -- after it ran normally for about 24 hours, all of a sudden we started seeing a greatly increased rate of timeouts when our worker roles fetch messages from the queue, along with a catastrophic drop in throughput (our application can now barely keep up with its own queue using 40 workers, whereas it usually gets by with just 2!) Ever since the timeouts started, they show no signs of letting up, keeping up at the same rate since it started happening.

A couple images from New Relic to illustrate:

[image]

[image]

While this isn't nearly enough information to provide a good answer, I'm just trying to figure out where I might start looking. I've got support tickets open with New Relic and Microsoft, but we're trying to investigate on our own as well. Could this be throttling? Some kind of resource exhaustion in my queue processor worker role? We don't see increased load on the WCF service, and we haven't changed Azure client libraries or changed much of anything in the code that processes the queue.

Comment: I would roll back your application updates and see if you return to a normal service.  If you are unable to do that I would be closely inspecting anything that is likely to result in a blocking call.  Drop in plenty of instrumentation in key areas of your code and see if there is a common place where code is taking a long time to execute.

Comment: I've been able to narrow down the issue since noticing it turned up in our test environment as well: it's the CloudQueue.DeleteMessage calls that are timing out (not every time, just intermittently, but often enough to cause problems). Will do some appropriate edits or move this to a new question shortly.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you enable analytics on your storage account to determine if the bottleneck is server side or client side/network related. Specifically, you can look at Storage Analytics Metrics table - AverageE2ELatency and AverageServerLatency properties to check if the issue is server side or client side.

You can learn more about Azure storage analytics from links below

Overview: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh343270.aspx

How to enable in portal: 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/

Metrics table Schema: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh343264.aspx

Blog post: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/08/03/windows-azure-storage-analytics.aspx